# Getline keeps on getting newline character. How can I avoid this?

Tags: c++, string, getline

Basically I first takes an integer as input and then test case follows. My each test case is an string. I am suppose to print the string back if the starting patten of string matches "HI A" and it is case-insensitive. I wrote the code below to accomplish to this. My problem is that when I press enter after each input, getline takes newline character as new input. I have tried to tackle this by using extra getline after each input but the issue is still there. Program gets stuck in the loop even though I have put a break condition. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int N;
    cin >>N;
    string nl;
    getline(cin,nl);
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        string s;
        getline(cin,s);
        //cout <<"string"<<s<<endl;
        int flag=0;
        if ((s.at(0)=='h'||s.at(0)=='H')&&(s.at(1)=='i'||s.at(1)=='I')&&(s.at(2)==' ')&&(s.at(3)=='a'||s.at(3)=='A')) flag=1;

        if (flag==1) cout << s;
        //cout << "not " <<s;
        string ne;
        cout << "i="<< i<<endl;
        if (i==N-1) {break;}
        getline(cin,ne);

    }
}
```

Here is sample input:

```
5
Hi Alex how are you doing
hI dave how are you doing
Good by Alex
hidden agenda
Alex greeted Martha by saying Hi Martha
```

Output should be:

```
Hi Alex how are you doing
```

Comment: Change `getline(cin,nl)` to `cin.ignore()` to dispose of the rest of the line after reading N. `cin.ignore()` reads and discards the rest of the line still unread from cin.

Comment: Please search for the functions `toupper` and `tolower`.  If you convert the character to upper or lower case, you reduce your comparisons by half.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `cin >>N` stops at the first non-numeric character, which is the newline. This you have a `getline` to read past it, that's good.

Each additional `getline` after that reads the entire line, *including the newline at the end*. By putting in a second `getline` you're skipping half your input.

Answer (score 15):

ignore() function does the trick. By default, it discards all the input suquences till new line character.

Other dilimiters and char limit can be specified as well.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/

In your case it goes like this.

```
    cin >> N;
    cin.ignore();
```

Answer (score 2):

So, your real problem isn't that `getline` eats newlines, but that your second `getline(cin, ne)` is eating a line...

And that is because you mistakenly think that you need two `getline` operations to read one line - or something like that. Mixing "linebased" and "itembased" input does have confusing ways to deal with newlines, so you do need something to "skip" the newline left behind frin `cin >> N;`, but once you have got rid of that, you only need ONE `getline` to read up and including the newline at the end of a line.

Answer (score 2):

I am writing this answer with the hopes that it may help someone else out there that wants a very simple solution to this problem.

In my case the problem was due to some files having different line endings such as '\r' vs. '\n'. Everything worked fine in windows but then it failed in Linux.

The answer was actually simple.  I created a function removeNewLineChar after each line was read in.  That way the char was removed.  The removeNewLineChar takes in the line that was read in and copies it over character by character into a new string but it avoids copying either of the newline characters.

Here is an example:

```
string trim(string line)
{
    string newString;

    for (char ch : line)
    {
        if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r')
            continue;
        newString += ch;
    }

    return newString;
}


//some function reading a file

while (getline(fin, line)) {
    line = trim(line);
    //... do something with the line
    line = "";
}
```

Comment: This was the exact problem I was facing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to accept the fact that getline will give you '\n' at the end. One solution is remove '\n' after getting it. Another solution is do not write the additional 'endl'. for example, for your problem, you can use this code

```
int N;
cin >> N;
string line;
getline(cin, line); // skip the first new line after N.
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  string line;
  getline(cin, line);
  string first4 = line.substr(0, 4);
  // convert to upper case.
  std::transform(first4.begin(), first4.end(), first4.begin(), std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::toupper)); // see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform
  if (first4 == "HI A") {
    cout << line;  // do not include "<< endl"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cin.ignore()` worked for me.

```
void House::provideRoomName()
{
    int noOfRooms;

    cout<<"Enter the number of Rooms::";
    cin>>noOfRooms;
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Enter name of the Rooms::"<<endl;
    cin.ignore();
    for(int i=1; i<=noOfRooms; i++)
    {
        std::string l_roomName;
        cout<<"Room"<<"["<<i<<"] Name::";
        std::getline(std::cin, l_roomName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string line;
std::cin>>std::ws; // discard new line not processed by cin
std::getline(std::cin,line);
```

From *Notes* section https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

```
When consuming whitespace-delimited input (e.g. int n; std::cin >> n;) any whitespace that follows, including a newline character, will be left on the input stream. Then when switching to line-oriented input, the first line retrieved with getline will be just that whitespace. In the likely case that this is unwanted behaviour, possible solutions include:

An explicit extraneous initial call to getline
Removing consecutive whitespace with std::cin >> std::ws
Ignoring all leftover characters on the line of input with cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```