# Press Enter to continue or q to quit c++

Tags: do-loops

I'm writing a c++ program that displays 2 outputs of a man to make it look like he is jumping if you press enter. If you enter 'q', the program is supposed to stop.  This is as far as I have gotten.

// This program will display a jumping man.

## include

## include

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
string user_input;

```
 do
{
    cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl
         << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl
         << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl 
         << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl;

    cout <<  "  O" << endl;
    cout << " /|\\" << endl;
    cout << " ( )" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    cout <<   "Press ENTER to continue or enter q to quit:";

    getline(cin, user_input);

    cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl
         << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl
         << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl 
         << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl;

    cout << " \\O/" << endl;
    cout << "  | " << endl;
    cout << " / \\" << endl << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------" <<endl;
    cout <<   "Press ENTER to continue or enter q to quit:";
} while(getline(cin, user_input));

return 0;
```

}

I have been trying for hours and I still can not figure out how to stop the program if you enter q.

I've tried variations of the while statement such as

while(getline(cin,user_input) && user_input =! 'q')

but it doesn't work. Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like homework which means this isn't the place ask. But I would assume it might have something to do with there not being any if statements to check the value given by the user. And your other attempt failed because of getline getting the entire newline not just the 'q' in this case.  Here's more [Getline keeps on getting newline character. How can I avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725522/getline-keeps-on-getting-newline-character-how-can-i-avoid-this). You could replace the check you tried with while(getline(cin,string) && string != "q\n")
Edit: I wanted this to be a comment but lack reputation.

Comment: This is not homework, I'm just trying to learn c++ coding and am at the early activities in the book I'm learning from. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Ok cool, what you might want to do is refactor your loop so that the check isn't like this while(read from cin and check) more like: {loop code ..... getline(cin,user_input); bool input = user_input != "q\n";} while(input) "\n" is the escape character for new line and prints the same as endl but is contained in the string"

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean here. Could you perhaps describe in more detail?

Comment: `cout<<"press enter to continue q to quit";  
getline(cin,user_input);  
result = user_input != "q" // set the result outside of loop header.
while(result) //continue while result is true (user_input not equal to q).
Im fond of using this style though.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out this morning and thought I would share for future reference.

## include

## include

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

string user_input;
int counter = 0;

```
do
{
    if ( counter % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl
        << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl
        << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl 
        << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl;

        cout <<  "  O" << endl;
        cout << " /|\\" << endl;
        cout << " ( )" << endl;
        cout << "------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    }

     if ( counter % 2 != 0)
     {
        cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl
         << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl
         << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl 
         << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl;

        cout << " \\O/" << endl;
        cout << "  | " << endl;
        cout << " / \\" << endl << endl;
        cout << "------------------------------------------------------------" <<endl;
     }

    cout << "Press ENTER to continue or enter q to quit:";
    getline (cin, user_input);

    if (user_input == "q")
{
    return 0;
}
counter = counter + 1;
} while (user_input != "q");
return 0;
```

If the loop repeat, denoted by int counter which adds one each loop, is even the program displays the man standing. Then, the prompt "Press ENTER to continue or 'q' to quit: " is displayed. It continues if the user enters ENTER, getline (cin, user_input). If the user enters 'q' the loop breaks (return 0;). If the loop is repeated, if the user presses ENTER, then the counter is now odd and the program displays the man jumping.