# Asking user how many names they want to input and storing the names in the array

Tags: java

This is beginner question I assume. So forgive me.

My problem is I want the user to input the number of names they want to input. Then, they will input the names and I will store them in an array and print it. But it seems like the program also stores "" blank after entering the number of names.

So for example, if I input 3 then I can only input two more. Let's say after inputting 3 I input "a" and "b" the program will print ["", "a", "b"].

It works fine if I'm asking for integers instead.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an extra nextLine() after you do nextInt(), otherwise, it will get an empty character at the beginning.

Do this:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("How many names will you insert?");
        int numNames = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine(); // NEEDS THIS
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numNames; i++ ) {
            System.out.println("Enter name " + i+1 + ": ");
            String name = in.nextLine();
            names.add(name);
        }
        System.out.println("Added names:");
        System.out.println(names);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that in.nextLine did the job. Can you explain why it would store the blank character? I'm just curious. Only if you know. No pressure.

Comment: You are welcome.
So the reason why you need to call nextLine before you start is nextInt stops at the first non-numeric character, which is the newline, so you need to skip that. This happens in many programming languages, this link explains why it happens in c++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725522/getline-keeps-on-getting-newline-character-how-can-i-avoid-this

Comment: Thank you. It seems like I can't Accept answers I don't know why. As soon as check the accept then refresh the page it goes back unchecked.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code, it should solve your problem.

```
System.out.println("Enter number of users name you want to enter");
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> users=new ArrayList<String>();
    
    int user_number=sc.nextInt();
    while(user_number!=0)
    {
        
        System.out.println("Enter user name");
        Scanner sc1=new Scanner(System.in);
        String user=sc1.nextLine();
        users.add(user);
        user_number--;
        
    }
          System.out.println(users);
```